# Google Chrome use alsa instead of pulseaudio

Tags: google-chrome, alsa, pulse-audio

I would like to make Google Chrome use alsa instead of PulseAudio so there is not a delay when watching netflix. However, I don't want to uninstall PulseAudio because I need to be able to use Skype.

I am using 64bit Arch Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is awfully old, but since there is no answer, I provide one now.

You can start Chrome with:

```
$ pasuspender -- google-chrome https://netflix.com
```

This effectively suspends PulseAudio and reserves the ALSA output device to the process being launched, Chrome in your case. That also means that no other software will be able to output sound through PulseAudio while Chrome is running under `pasuspender`: you'll need to close this Chrome instance in order to get your PulseAudio back for others to use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up uninstalling pulseaudio and using just alsa. I used apulse for skype an other pulse only apps. I am going to accept this because I assume it works.